# Installation error: package LSB has unmet dependencies in Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: apt, 20.04

I need to install a newer license server on my Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS server.
The license server need the lsb package, which cannot be installed showing the error:
(I use apt install lsb...)

```
lsb: Depends: lsb-core [...] lsb-printing ... but it is not going to be installed.
When I follow the shown packages (lsb-core and lsb-printing are the first of a longer list) I come to that point:
libc6-dev: Depends: libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.2) but 2.310ubuntu9.3 is to be installed
```

There I got stuck since 6 weeks now. For me it looks like a wrong dependency inside that libc6-dev package and I don't know how to solve that. I've even tried to download the needed packages and try dpkg -i ... but same error appears. Anything I can do now?
Thanks in advance!

Jens...

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show  us `apt-cache policy libc6`

Comment: libc6:
  Installed: 2.31-0ubuntu9.3
  Candidate: 2.31-0ubuntu9.3
  Version table:
 *** 2.31-0ubuntu9.3 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.31-0ubuntu9.2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2.31-0ubuntu9 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages

Comment: `sudo apt install --reinstall libc6=2.31-0ubuntu9.2`

Comment: Perfect, problem solved. Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

From the comments...

As [suggested by nobody](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1388962/installation-error-package-lsb-has-unmet-dependencies-in-ubuntu-20-04-3-lts#comment2399251_1388962), OP ran:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libc6=2.31-0ubuntu9.2
```

To install the correct version of the `libc6` package.